# Getting DbContext Set<T> by Interface

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, dependency-injection

**Background**

I have a multi-layered application that I am trying to refactor. My Data layer is essentially just a EF Database Context (and all of its entities).
One of the goals I am trying to accomplish is to remove the dependency between my Biz layer and my Data layer (using Dependency Injection) so that my unit tests do not have to hit the database. To do this, I created a simple interface that my context implements, IDataStore.

```
public interface IDataStore
{
   void Insert<T>(T entity) where T:class;
   void Update<T>(T entity) where T:class;
   void Delete<T>(T entity) where T:class;
   T GetById<T>(int id) where T:class;
   IQueryable<T> All<T>() where T:class;
}

public partial class MyContext:DbContext,IDataStore
{
   public void Insert<T>(T entity) where T:class{
      this.Set<T>().Add(entity);
      this.SaveChanges();
   }
   ...
   public IQueryable<T> All<T>() where T:class{
      return this.Set<T>();
   }
}
```

Using an IoC contianer, I was able to remove all refrences in my Biz layer to MyContext (Instead refering to IDataStore), but I'm still stuck refering to my specific entity classes. In the example below, I'm using an IDataStore, but I'm also using a Data.Color (one of my entity classes).

```
public static void MyBizMethod(){
   ...
   IDataStore store = myUnityContainer.Resolve<IDataStore>();
   List<string> colorNames = store.All<Data.Color>().Select(c => c.name).ToList();
   ...
}
```

The next thing I did was create an IColor interface and used a partial class to make Data.Color implement IColor. I then modified my Biz-layer logic to call DataStore.All< IColor>() instead of DataStore.All< Data.Color>();

```
public interface IColor{
   string name;
}

public partial class Color: IColor { }
```

and in my Biz layer....

```
public static void MyBizMethod(){ 
   ...
   List<string> colorNames = store.All<IColor>().Select(c => c.name).ToList();
   ...
}
```

**The Problem**

When DbContext.Set< T>() gets called using an interface for T (In my case IColor) i get an exception because the context has a DbSet< Color> not DbSet< IColor>.

Is there someway make the context have a DbSet< IColor> instead? If not, is there some other way to genericly retrieve an DbSet from a DbContext by interface? I'd really like to avoid writing a giant switch statement.

Or... Is there a better way to do this altogether? Preferably one that doesn't involve creating a seperate interface for every type of entity I have,

**Update**

The post left by @doctor addresses my initial question (how to query a table by interface), but the other posts explain that that is not even necessary (since my entity classes are already abstracted anyway) and I feel like they helped more with the root of my problem

Nevertheless, I wanted to see if the other post's solution would work for what I had originally asked, and it does... for the most part. The notable exception is the .Include() method for IQueryable.

Consider the following code example:

```
var people = store.All<IPerson>().Where(p => p.IsAlive).Include("Children").ToList();
foreach (IPerson parent in people)
{
   Console.WriteLine(parent.Name + " has " + p.Children.Count() + " children");
}
```

When calling store.All< Person>(), the .Include() gets translated to SQL as would be expected. When using IPerson however, it appears to be completely ignored and a separate query is generated every time through the loop. The funny thing is that the .Where() clause gets correctly translated in both cases (I verified using SQL profiler). Anyway, I've decided not to implement a separate interface for every entity I have and instead reference the entities directly. Just wanted to point out the odd .Include() behavior.

Comment: Generally in situations like this you don't need to abstract away the models themselves, just the method of accessing them, which you are already well on the way to doing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to query all tables that implement an interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26385341/how-to-query-all-tables-that-implement-an-interface)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most of the time when using Entity Framework, people don't put business logic on the entities themselves. They use *services* like your "Biz layer" class to consume the data represented on those entities.

If you follow this pattern, entities don't need to be *mocked* because they are *data structures*, not *services*. You can just as easily create a real instance of them.

Furthermore, the class types themselves in Entity Framework are representative of actual collections of data: you might have a few of them implement the same interface, but when you're saying "I want the set of `Color`s" you're asking for the ones from a particular table in the database. Since you're already tightly-coupled to the notion of a set of `Color`s existing in your data store, you're not likely to gain anything by using an interface to represent them at this level.

Comment: The link @dotctor put answered my inital question, but now I'm interested in know why entities wouldn't be abstracted in this case. Wouldn't this mean that any alternative implementaion for IDataStore would be dependent on MyContext? Just as an example... If I wanted to store data to a xml file instead of a database (not going to, but if I did) wouldn't my "XmlDataStore" have to at least refrence the assembly that MyDataStore is in?

Comment: It would not be. Your models are POCOs (Plain Old CLR Objects) thus are usable regardless of what your backing is. You would be responsible for getting them to and from the backing store with whatever technology you use. In your above example, you're would either use a technology that serializes them to XML and stores them, or you would handle the serialization and deserialization in a custom class based on `IDataStore` that you write yourself.

Comment: @NuclearProgrammer: Like Bradford indicated, your models themselves have a different "reason for change" than your Entity Framework context does. They are going to change as your core business model changes, whereas your EF context changes if you switch to a different business layer. Therefore, your concrete classes interacting with the EF context should not be the same classes interacting with your domain models.

Comment: "XmlDataStore" would only reference the assembly that your models are in--and those can be kept separate from your Entity Framework context. If you feel that these models are too tightly-coupled to your SQL Schema to be used as "just POCOs", you might consider creating a set of POCOs that represent the data you expect your business layer to interact with, and make your data layer's sole responsibility be to implement methods that map from your database layer to these POCO types.

Comment: This kind of breaks as soon as you go to implement DDD, where your entities have self-contained business logic. The lack of DI support in EF Core is strongly highlighted as soon as you start moving outside of the assumption that Entities are essentially POCOs. Which necessitates a whole host of what would be unnecessary workarounds

Comment: @DouglasGaskell: That is correct. I've come to see Entity Framework models as easy-to-work-with representations of your persistence data model. I wouldn't use them as Domain Model objects. To be honest, I haven't really found it worthwhile to use DDD-style classes in general: when I've tried I find that I end up injecting services into methods on my domain models, and creating a lot of two-way coupling. It doesn't seem to simplify things or make the code more correct or more maintainable.